# linear algebra - challenging proof (property of definite real matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, contest-math, positive-definite

I struggle with the following proof from linear algebra:

Prove:
[$A \in $ $ \mathbb{M}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{R}) $ is positive definite] $\implies$ $[\forall i \in \{1, ..., n\}: a_{i,i} > 0$]

Tried direct algebraic manipulations from $x^TAx$, but I did not derive any conclusions.

Any help/advice/solution very, very, very appreciated!!!

Comment: You know that $x^T A x > 0$ for any nonzero $x$.  Have you tried any specific values for $x$?

Comment: Yes. Got no conclusions at all. Could you give me more help?

Comment: What values of $x$ did you try?

Comment: Write the vector $x$ as a vector of variables $x=(x_1,x_2,\ldots,x_n)$. Expand $x^TAx$ into an expression involving the constants  $a_{ij}$'s and the individual variables.  Now use the hint given by littleO.

Comment: Did this. Put vectors  [0,...0,1,...,0] (1 on i-th coordinate, i from {1,...,n}) to the expression. Got the fact that sum of constants at i-th column must be positive. From there I am unable to proceed further.

Comment: That's a good choice of $x$.  Try it for the case $n = 2$.  So $A = \begin{bmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} \end{bmatrix}$.  Let's pick $x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \end{bmatrix}$.  What is $x^T A x$ equal to in this case?

Comment: Now I see. x^T * A *x  in the case x=[1 0 ]^T yields : a_{1,1} > 0. Analogically, in the case x=[0 1]^T, the result is : a_{2,2} > 0. In general case (n arbitrary),  vector [0,...,0,1,0,...,0] implies that: a_{i,i} > 0.

Comment: Must have done mistakes in algebraic manipulations at some point.

Comment: Besides, I now understand the trick of putting specific values of x (by the condition "for all non-zero x" - in other words, for any selected form of non-zero x).

Comment: Therefore,  proof completed.

Comment: User "little0" - thanks for help!!! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 1):

I'll post an answer so the question can be marked as answered.  As discussed in the comments: if $x$ is the $i$th standard basis vector, then
$$
x^T A x = a_{i,i} > 0.
$$

(Here $a_{i,i}$ is the $i$th diagonal entry of $A$.)